# Kafka - Topics, Consumer Groups And Consumer Replicas

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, confluent-platform

I'm new to Kafka and would like to know the best approach for configuring the topics, partitions, consumer groups and consumer app replicas.

Working on an existing setup, the configuration handed down is as follows:

1. 10 topics
2. Each topic has its own group i.e. *topic1-group1*, *topic2-group2* and so on.
3. Each topic has 5 partitions
4. The Java consumer app has 5 (intentionally same as number of partitions, I'm told) replicas (k8s pods) which use Spring Kafka's `@KafkaListener`

**Q1.** I'd like to know if this is the configuration that will offer the best performance (high throughput and low latency)?

The consumer app sends the messages to only ONE downstream system which makes me think that all the topics (and all their partitions + consumer app replicas) can share a single consumer group (let's call it *main-group*).

**Q2.** Would this offer better or worse performance than having dedicated group for each topic?

---

**Sub question:**

**Q3.** Can ONE `@KafkaListener` work with 10 topics each with dedicated consumer groups given it has only 1 `containerGroup` and 1 `containerFactory` parameter?

Thanks

Comment: You would have a group per interested consumer application, not one-to-one  per topic

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer. That's what I was thinking. Since the consumer app is running currently with one group per topic, what can you say would be impacting it and how?

Comment: There's no impact. It's just unnecessary unless you better explain your use case, since one group can track multiple topics